# Enrich amp-ima-video with features from amp-video

Tags: amp-html

The native `amp-video` has tons of features like (rotate-to-full, double tap on right or left....) but in order to use ads, I'm pretty much forced to use `amp-ima-video` which lacks these features sadly :(

Is there any way to use `amp-video` features in `amp-ima-video`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried checking the attributes of each component in the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ima-video) to find out some useful ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible. Can you please file a feature request [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) for any missing `amp-ima-video` feature.

Comment: Yes I did, here's the link: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/created_by/felerticia